# is there a canonical way to grab all idents from a particular datomic namespace?

Tags: clojure, datomic

say I had `:user/name` and `:user/gender` installed as datomic schema.

```
(pprint (d/q '[:find ?ident :where
               [?e :db/ident ?ident]
               [_ :db.install/attribute ?e]] (d/db conn)))
```

finds all the db.install/attributes

```
 #{[:db/code] [:user/gender] [:fressian/tag] [:db/unique] [:user/name] [:db/fn] 
 [:db/noHistory] [:db/fulltext] [:db/lang] [:db/valueType] [:db/doc]
 [:db/isComponent] [:db.install/function] [:db/cardinality] [:db/txInstant] [:db/index]}
```

however, I only want to list items in the :user namespace

```
[:user/gender] [:user/name]
```

what should I add to the query or is there a function that does it automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out

```
(d/q '[:find ?ident :where
           [?e :db/ident ?ident]
           [_ :db.install/attribute ?e]
           [(.toString ?ident) ?val]
           [(.startsWith ?val ":user")]] (d/db *conn*))

;; => #{[:user/gender] [:user/firstName]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the Tupelo Datomic library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/src/tupelo/datomic.adoc) to grab all EIDs for a given partition.  Just use:

```
(ns xyz
  (:require [tupelo.datomic :as td] ...

  ; Create a partition named :people (we could namespace it like :db.part/people if we wished)
  (td/transact *conn* 
    (td/new-partition :people ))

; Find all EID's in the :people partition
(let [people-eids (td/partition-eids *conn* :people) ]
   ...)
```

More information can be found in [the Datomic Mailing List](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/datomic/partition%7Csort:date/datomic/eQQnnqYl67Y/ZMvrYL4eEgAJ).  Enjoy!